# GNU Octave: reading data with NA values using textscan(...)

Tags: octave, textscan

I need to read data from an ASCII file where missing values are given as NA. Using textscan(...) does not seem to work, because textscan(...) seems to stop reading/parsing at the first occurrence of NA.

Here's a simple demonstration of the issue:

```
x = textscan ( "1 ; 2 ; 3\n4 ; NA ; 6" , '%d %d %d' , 'Delimiter' , ';' , 'ReturnOnError' , false )
error: textscan: Read error in field 2 of row 2
```

I have also tried to tell textscan(...) to interpret NA as "empty value", but no luck:

```
x = textscan ( "1 ; 2 ; 3\n4 ; NA ; 6" , '%d %d %d' , 'Delimiter' , ';' , 'TreatAsEmpty' , 'NA' , 'ReturnOnError' , false )
error: textscan: Read error in field 2 of row 2
```

Can someone explain what's going on, or how to make this work?

Note that is just a simplified example to illustrate the problem. The format of the data in my files is a bit more complex, and I really depend on textscan(...) to parse it; I don't think I can easily do it without textscan(...).

(I am running Octave 4.2.1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NA` is defined for floating point numbers so you should use `'%f'` conversion specifier instead of `'%d'`.

```
x = textscan ( "1 ; 2 ; 3\n4 ; NA ; 6" , '%f %f %f' ,
    'Delimiter' , ';' , 'ReturnOnError' , false )
```

Comment: This is not consistent with MATLAB though. :/ Tested in both MATLAB and Octave. Works in Octave.

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks,  I think `NaN` should be used instead of `NA` can you test it?

Comment: @SardarUsama If  `%d`   is used NA is converted to `0` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: In MATLAB, problem is caused by `\n`. See here: [#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAPln.jpg) and [#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCcyy.jpg)

Comment: [*.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJK47.jpg) Anyway, your answer is fine and correct as it is since the question is asked about Octave